# Rearrange array of objects by date

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object

I receive from the API all active and completed tasks. I want to adapt this object to use SectionList (React-Native), using each date field (dataCadastro) **to separate by day**. For example https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist

```
{
  active: [
    {
      id: 1,
      dataCadastro: '2020-06-15T14:33:45.4807609+00:00',
      status: 1,
      description: '',

    },
    {
      id: 2,
      dataCadastro: '2020-06-15T15:33:45.4807609+00:00',
      status: 1,
      description: '',

    },
  ],
  completed: [
    {
      id: 3,
      dataCadastro: '2020-05-19T14:33:45.4807609+00:00',
      status: 1,
      description: '',

    },
    {
      id: 4,
      dataCadastro: '2020-05-19T15:33:45.4807609+00:00',
      status: 1,
      description: '',

    }
  ]
}
```

A result like this would be great:

```
const dataTest = [
    {
      title: '2020-06-15', // All tasks for the 15th of June.
      data: [
        {
          id: 1,
          dataCadastro: '2020-06-15T14:33:45.4807609+00:00',
          status: 1,
          description: '',

        },
       {
          id: 2,
          dataCadastro: '2020-06-15T15:33:45.4807609+00:00',
          status: 1,
          description: '',

        }
      ],
    }, {...}  
  ];
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is merge all of the data together.

```
const allTasks = data.active.concat(data.completed);
```

Then you need to aggregate them by date.

```
const dataObject = allTasks.reduce((dataObject, task) => {
    const date = new Date(task.dataCadastro.toLocaleDateString());

    if (!dataObject[date]) dataObject[date] = { title: date, data: [] };
    dataObject[date].data.push[task];
    return dataObject;
}, {});
```

Then you need to convert the data object into an array and sort it by date.

```
const data = Object.values(dataObject).sort((a, b) => a.title - b.title);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data inside `active` or `completed` are of same type then you can use just map it by taking entries:

```js
var obj = { active: [ { id: 1, dataCadastro: '2020-06-15T14:33:45.4807609+00:00', status: 1, description: '', }, { id: 2, dataCadastro: '2020-06-15T15:33:45.4807609+00:00', status: 1, description: '', }, ], completed: [ { id: 3, dataCadastro: '2020-05-19T14:33:45.4807609+00:00', status: 1, description: '', }, { id: 4, dataCadastro: '2020-05-19T15:33:45.4807609+00:00', status: 1, description: '', } ]};

var result = Object.entries(obj).map(([_,data])=>({title: data[0].dataCadastro, data }));

console.log(result);
```

Otherwise you can go for `reduce`:

```js
var obj = { active: [ { id: 1, dataCadastro: '2020-06-15T14:33:45.4807609+00:00', status: 1, description: '', }, { id: 2, dataCadastro: '2020-06-15T15:33:45.4807609+00:00', status: 1, description: '', }, ], completed: [ { id: 3, dataCadastro: '2020-05-19T14:33:45.4807609+00:00', status: 1, description: '', }, { id: 4, dataCadastro: '2020-05-19T15:33:45.4807609+00:00', status: 1, description: '', } ]};

var result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [_, data])=>{
  data.forEach(elem=>{
     title = elem.dataCadastro.slice(0,10)
     acc[title] = acc[title] || {title, data:[]};
     acc[title].data.push(elem);
   });
 return acc;
},{});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```